# redirectring result of a program in a specific directory

Tags: linux, redirect

I have a program which produce a directory ,instead of creating the directory in current directory I want to specify a path:

```
./program x > directoryfoo
```

I am getting this error:

```
directoryfoo is a directory.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a fully qualified path to create the output like

```
ls >/home/Myfile.txt
```

and be sure that your user account has write permission in the directory.

Comment: myfile.txt is a file , as I mentioned this program makes a directory so i can not give a filename

Comment: Actually this is not my program,it is a program that takes an input and based on input makes a folder with a bunch of flies in it , instead of making folder in current directory I want to specify a path

Comment: dont use redirection operator, just use `./ProgramX "/home/MyHome/"` and if it still doesn't work then the only option is to change directory to your choice.

Answer (score 0):

If the program creates a directory you cannot influence where this directory is created, except for:

- you modify the program
- you intercept the mkdir() system call

**EDIT**

How to intercept a system call using a self-made library is described [here](http://uu-kk.blogspot.de/2010/12/intercepting-linux-system-calls-part-ii.html) and you can easily find other examples. I don't know if there is any ready-made tool capable of doing this if you are not into programming.

Comment: @ scai :- You can, if the mkdir is using the user provided parameters.

Comment: @Anonymous that's correct, but I assumed shaq already looked for such an command line option.

Comment: I can't modify the program ,I don't know how deal with mkdir

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest moving to the directory prior to executing the program:

```
cd direcotoryfoo
$OLDPWD/program x
```